# Having Issue On Bootstrap 3 SlideDown() hidden Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/zzdL5jp7/) and let me know why the `change()` function is not able to `slideDown()` a `hidden` element in Bootstrap 3?

Here is the code I have

```
$(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
        if($(this).val()== 'Dog') {
            $('#hidden-list-1').slideDown();
        }
        if($(this).val()== 'Bird'){
            $('#hidden-list-2').slideDown();  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the other answers have already mentioned the issue is boostrap has a style like this

```
.hidden{
  display: none !important;
}
```

One way to solve this is by removing hidden class.

```
$('#hidden-list-1').hide().removeClass('hidden').slideDown();
```

Here is a demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/zzdL5jp7/3/**

Comment: This was the best option for me, not limited to bootstrap. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue of the important tag in CSS. From the Bootstrap documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/css/), the show and hidden classes are marked with important:

```
   .show {
      display: block !important;
    }
    .hidden {
      display: none !important;
    }
```

The css changes applied by jQuery slideDown() are most likely getting ignored. If you take this out and replace with a `style="display:none;"` without the important, the slideDown() will work. I added that to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zzdL5jp7/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is because the hidden class forces an element to always be hidden. I'm pretty sure it does something like:

```
display: none !important;
```

So you have to modify your code to remove that class after sliding the element down. Or use your own CSS to hide the element (so you don't have `!important` there.

If you modify your JSFiddle to have the CSS:

```
#hidden-list-1 {
    display: none;
}
```

And remove the `hidden` class, you'll see that it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `hidden` class you've added to `#hidden-list-1` and `#hidden-list-2` is overriding the display property change done by your JS. Removing the `hidden` class and declaring both elements hidden in CSS will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

update your css code

```
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```